# ConfigSlurper().parse() not working

Tags: groovy

It seems that for whatever reason my ConfigSlurper().parse is not working properly. Whenever I pass it any configuration if is either hardcoded or in a config.groovy file it creates an empty map.
this is what I have:

```
    def parser = '''foo:{
        path: "path"
        hidden: true
        version: Framework_V4_0
        host: localhost:8080
            }'''

    ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("src/config.groovy").toURL())
    println new File("src/config.groovy").toURL()
    println conf.app
```

and the config.groovy file:

```
app {
    path: "path"
    hidden: true
    version: "Framework_V4_0"
    host: "localhost:8080"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is incorrect. As explained in the [ConfigSlurper documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html), it expects configuration files defined in the form of Groovy scripts.

```
def parser = '''app {
    path = 'path'
    hidden = 'true'
    version = 'Framework_V4_0'
    host = 'localhost:8080'
}'''

ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(parser)
println conf
```

PS: `File#toURL()` is deprecated, don't use it.

---

Reading it from a file in Groovy is straight-forward:

```
def parser = '''app {
    path = 'path'
    hidden = 'true'
    version = 'Framework_V4_0'
    host = 'localhost:8080'
}'''

def file = new File('config')
file << parser
ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(file.text)
println conf
```

Comment: omg, it actually work, thank you very much, but I still have a question, is there any way to get if from a file?

Comment: @StefanCiprianIuga Don't thank me, thank Groovy's awesomeness ;)